# How to extract articles using python-readability?

Tags: python, django

```
    url = 'http://wired.com/'
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    readable_article = Document(html).summary()
    print(readable_article)
    readable_title = Document(html).short_title()
    data = Document(html).get_article(["p", "pre", "td"], ["h1"])
    print(data)
```

**Gettting Error**

```
File "/home/sayone/virtual/poster/lib/python3.4/site-packages/readability/readability.py", line 211, in get_article
    best_candidate['content_score'] * 0.2])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the error is in the code you have presented. there is no `best_candidate` like the error describes.

Comment: Can you show me What or how should be the parameters for article()  with example...thanx